# Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\ss, ClaimsCount=22

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Few users not able to access SharePoint site gets error "Something went wrong" and in log found :

> "Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True,
>   UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\ss, ClaimsCount=22".

Could anyone help me to fix this issue, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when I browse to my test sharepoint site, it will redirect to the adfs url. I enter my credentials again and nothing happens. uls log shows non-OAuth request. Isauthentication=false, useridentityname=, claimscount=0. How do I get "Isauthentication=false" to true??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may be something with the distributed cache.

You can try the following:

- Restart distributed cache service
- Remove and add the user permissions from the site